# make a button in html that can change text of a paragraph each time you click on it

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to make a website with many paragraph telling people about fitness. butin the website I am creating it is impossible for me to add a button that could change the text of the paragraph when I click on it.
I would like to add a button that could change the text each time I click on it.
that button should be able to change the text of the paragraph each time I click on it.
this button should change the days of the week, so if I click one time it will change Monday to Tuesday ect.
Also I am using notepad if it is possible to do it I need some help

Comment: I think you need to look online for a basic HTML / website building course.

Comment: I have already visit the help center and there was no question related to what I need

Comment: online I could only get how to change button text on click but not what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and a counter

```js
var a=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var count=0;
function x()
{
if(count>6)
count=0;
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=a[count++];
}
```

```html
<p id="a">Sunday</p>
<button id="b" onclick="x()">click</button>
```

Comment: as you showed me when I put these codes in notepad the codes for var = ect it comes as a text what should I do

Comment: so what should i do if want them to work, do i need to use another app which is not notepad

Comment: Do i have to use another app which is not notepad

Comment: write html in notepad ,in the head add the script above. save the file with extension .html. open the file in a browser. press f12 and you will see the output in the console